# Rails event polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating an event system and I was wondering if my polymorphic association is correct. the events can be national and be broadcasted for the whole group (a group has many shops) or local and be broadcasted for one or more shops.

I have 2 types of jingles that will be broadcasted at the same time after reaching a threshold:  "primary_media" and "generic_media", the primary media is the media that will be broadcasted in the shop that reached the threshold and at the same time, the generic media is the media will be the media broadcasted in the other shops of the group.

my migration:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.integer :primary_media_id
      t.string  :primary_media_type
      t.integer :generic_media_id
      t.string  :generic_media_type
      t.string  :created_by
      t.string  :updated_by
      t.integer :threshold
      t.references :eventable, polymorphic: true, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :events
  end
end
```

event.rb EDITED

```
belongs_to :eventable, polymorphic: true
has_many   :event_join
```

group.rb EDITED

```
has_many :event_join, as: :eventable,
has_many :events, through: :event_join
```

shop.rb EDITED

```
has_many :event_join, as: :eventable
has_many :events, through: :event_join
```

So as you can see, it is quite complex and was wondering if you guys could help me go in the right direction in the creation of this system.

Knowing that a shop belongs to a group. I was reading the association chapter in the online documentation and I was wondering if the self join method would be more relevant. Sorry for this newbie question, i'm quite new to rails and polymorphic associations.

Edited: I created a joint table

joint table:

```
class EventJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :event_join, :id => false do |t|
      t.string  :event
      t.integer :eventable_id,
      t.string  :eventable_type,
      t.boolean :status,
      t.string  :created_by,
      t.string  :updated_by
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :event_join
  end
end
```

Comment: Hm, I don't really get what you're asking. Is something not working or do you have a feeling that your code could be improved in some way?

Comment: I'm just worried that I may be going in the wrong way to accomplish what I am aiming to do so i am looking for some advice from a more experienced rails developer than me so I won't have to start all over. I also have a feeling that my code could be improved ^^.

Comment: OK, my first impression is that it seems redundant to both have polymorphic and normal associations. I would go for the polymorphic only at first and see how far that goes. I don't really see why you specify the foreign key, that's usually not needed unless you have some legacy database.

Comment: I edited my code. In order to seperate local events from national events. Is the event_joint table a good idea ?